# How to properly route pages on ReactJS with React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I try to route my pages.. but when I copy some URL link from the page and want to show to other people.. They see 404 Page's not found..

I use this simple code of React:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

I have more pages.. but when I copy/paste a URL address without some pages is show.
How can I fix that ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer as we can't know how it's deployed

Comment: I add   "homepage": "https://website.com", into package.json and use npm run build in terminal. After I zipped build folder and unzipped the same folder on the hosting

Answer (score -1):

this depends on the router version used. example for version 4.
i create codepen https://codepen.io/romanown/pen/ZEQjrXm and its worked. changed to working on codepen when i go to menu labels. but going by web address not worked on codepen. for it need real local or network server or hosting.
those who put a minus at least write for what.

html

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

js

```
const {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} = ReactRouterDOM

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
const App = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
)
ReactDOM.render((
    <App />
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Just when I try to copy link of users or about and when I paste the link somewhere users see 404 Not found.....